# What to use instead of `static const TCHAR *`

Tags: c++, c++11, legacy-code

Many old C/C++ projects use:

```
static TCHAR *x(_T("hello"));
```

... to define strings, however ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from a string literal to `TCHAR *` (aka `wchar_t *`), so I am looking for a safe alternative to writing these `static TCHAR *` lines.

Changing them to `std::wstring x(L"hello"))` poses other issues like "already defined" errors, so what to do?

Comment: (https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: What's wrong with `static TCHAR const *x(_T("hello"));` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten according to OP's comment on my answer the code base as a whole is not const-correct, so that doesn't compile.

Comment: @Quentin I think OP is stuck then, const casting std::string::c_str will work until there is an accidental cast of one actually declared const.

Comment: @RichardCritten You don't have to `const_cast` at all.

Comment: "TCHAR * (aka wchar_t *)". No. You're missing the (historical) point of `TCHAR`. It's either `char` or `wchar_t*`, depending on the `_UNICODE` macro. If you're going to ignore non-Unicode builds (reasonable; it's the 21st century after all) , then you shouldn't be messing with `TCHAR`.

Comment: @MSalters interesting - any chance you can amend the macro I made inorder to take this into account?

Comment: @serup: "Amend the macro"? I don't think you should be using any macro, so the question _which_ macro is moot.

Comment: @MSalters - see my answer - I use Quentins answer and add a macro to help make it easier, however it would be much better if your historical point was added to the macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is a const-correctness one, so you don't have to touch `static` (which handles linkage). This:

```
static std::wstring x = L"hello";
```

will have roughly the same meaning as the original code.

A non-const `wchar_t *` to that string's data can be obtained in several ways:

- (C++17 and up) `x.data()`;
- `&x[0]` (not formally *required* to be nul-terminated, but an implementation would have to be insane to do otherwise). This can also be wrapped in a function to avoid murking arond with operator precedence:

  ```
  wchar_t *data(std::wstring &string) { return &string[0]; }
  ```
- Declaring a companion variable for each string to keep a single identifier:

  ```
  static std::wstring x = L"hello";
  static wchar_t *x_c = &x[0];
  ```

Comment: Yes well I know this approach, however I will then have to use following at all places were x is used :  const_cast<wchar_t*>(x.c_str())
 -- and this is pretty ugly to look at

Comment: @serup you can use `&x[0]`, wrap it into a function for operator precedence comfort, or you can declare companion variables of the form `static wchar_t *x_c = &x[0];`.

Comment: Not really sure I understand - could you make a full example

Comment: @serup I expanded on these ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define staticTCHARptr( x , y )  static std::wstring _##x=y; static wchar_t *x = &_##x[0];
```

Then use it like this:

```
staticTCHARptr(X,L"hello");
```

instead of this:

```
static TCHAR* X(_T("hello"));
```

Now it is not needed to convert on all places where the X was originally used

Comment: Caution, identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved at global scope. Use a recognizable prefix instead.

Comment: The "already defined elsewhere:  comment suggests that you are abusing `static` here. I suspect you are putting this in a header file? Because the `static` is causing you to have multiple copies of `x`. And yes, you can now change `x` through the `TCHAR*`, but you'll be changing one copy and not the others.

Comment: As for the `TCHAR*`, you're no longer using it here so that at least is an improvement. I'd just rename `staticTCHARptr` to `wstringAndPointer` because that's what you are really defining there.

Comment: @MSalters reason for naming it, is to make the refactoring of old code easier - all places where static TCHAR* is used, then replace with staticTCHARptr -- however I see your point, however if another one is to do the refactoring, then perhaps wstringAndPointer is not abvious